# Starting multiple processes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When developing, I start my `main` from Eclipse and everything's fine, but now, I'm working on a web application (using embedded Jetty), which needs multiple processes. Currently there are three of them and more is to come.

I can start all of them with a few clicks on the run button, but it's getting uncomfortable. I'm using it a lot as a new process stops the old one, so I always work with the current version. *Unless I forget to start a process (or confuse them and start one multiple times while missing another).*

I could write a trivial class starting all of them in background, but then I won't get them writing to own eclipse console and there was no way to debug them.

So I'm asking: Is there a way how to make Eclipse start multiple processes with a single action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this using the [Composite launcher](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/composite-launcher) plugin.

Disclaimer : While the plugin page says it support Neon, it did not work for me when I tested. I managed to get it to work on Mars.2 package.

Once the plugin is successfully installed, you will have a new option "Composite launch" in run configurations :

[image]

Select the option, and all you have to do is group the run configurations you want to execute at once under this new configuration.

Comment: On Mars. the plugin is pretty buggy: 1. Selecting the parts to run is plain terrible (unsorted list, items found be Ctrl-F get added randomly). 2. Every run stays in the Debug view with no way to remove it. +++ All that said, it's very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could create you own launcher if you want to master the customization of you process startups : [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/debug_launch_adding.htm?resultof=%22%6C%61%75%6E%63%68%65%72%22%20)